# Why is Dervish so rich?

Tags: darren-shan, the-demonata

In the Demonata series by Darren Shan, Grubbs's uncle Dervish (introduced in the first book and a major character from there onwards) is very rich: he lives in a mansion with all mod cons, has teams of lawyers to handle the situation at the end of book 1, and so on. As Grubbs puts it in book 3:

> (my uncle—he mucho reeeech)

**Where did all Dervish's money come from?**

- Did he inherit a huge pile of cash? But his brother, Grubbs's father, never seemed to be on the same financial level as Dervish.
- Did he earn it all himself somehow? But he's not that old (in his thirties, I'd guess, though I don't remember for sure), and our glimpse of his younger self in book 2 doesn't *seem* much like an up-and-coming business mogul or the like.

Maybe this is elaborated upon somewhere in book 1? This is the only book I don't actually have to hand (since I borrowed it from the library years ago before buying the rest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>It doesn't look like anyone has noticed this Tumbleweed-eligible question, so I found the answer myself :-)</sup>

### **Dervish's wealth is mostly from a family fortune which his brother didn't touch, but he also earned a little from the antiques trade.**

I managed to dig out a copy of book 1, and found the relevant passage in chapter 4 (emphasis mine):

> "I dabble in antiques," he says. "Rare books are my speciality - particularly books regarding the occult." [...]
>
> "You must be good at it, to afford a place like this," I say, sliding away from the larger questions and issues.
>
> "It's a hobby," he demurs, leading me down a long corridor full of framed portraits and photographs. **"The money's good, but I don't worry too much about it."**
>
> "Then how do you pay for all this?" I ask nosily.
>
> Dervish quickens his pace. I think he's avoiding the question, but then he stops at one of the older portraits and points at it. "Recognise him?" [...] "He was your great-great-great-grandfather. Bartholomew Garadex. That's our original family name, on our paternal side - it got shortened to Grady around your greatgrandfather's time." [...] **"Bartholomew was a sublimely clever man. He started with nothing but had amassed a fortune by the time of his death. We're still living off of it - at least, I am. Cal preferred to make his own way in the world, and only dipped into the family coffers in emergencies."**
>
> "How much is left?" I enquire.
>
> "Quite a lot," Dervish says vaguely. "Your great-great-grandfather - one of old Bart's boys -  wasted most of it. Then his son - the one who changed the family name - restored it. **It's been fairly constant since, much of it tied up in bonds and properties which yield steady profits.**"